# What is the difference between “Java Build Path” and “Deployment assembly” in Eclipse dynamic web project IDE?

Tags: java, eclipse

I found one answer to a similar question in StackOverflow, however, it is not very clear to me. Can someone throw more light on it?

For example, I am supposed to put the org.json.jar library in deployment assembly if I want my servlets to run and give me a JSON object. Adding this library only in Java Build Path gives me the error of JSONObject class not found at runtime.